# Raising after an all in

Tags: texas-hold-em

In this situation, the blinds are 200/400 in a No Limit tournament. First to act raises to 1600, next player calls, small blind folds, and big blind goes all-in with only 1800.

**Can the first player reraise the second player?**

Basically, is the 200 extra that the big blind pushed all-in considered a raise opening up more rounds of betting or, is it too low to be considered a raise?

Answer (score 9):

No. It is too small of a raise. Since the original raise was a raise of 1200 (1600-400=1200) the raise by the big blind would have to be at least an additional 1200 (i.e. 2800 total) to re-open the action to the original raiser.

Comment: I would like to add that, if the raise is at least a 2800 total, then side-pots are built. See here: http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/462/309

Comment: Note that in Limit games, there is a half-size rule where betting reopens if the all-in raise is at least half the minimum. This rule is sometimes wrongly applied to No Limit games by casino floors, which would wrongly allow further raises in your example had the big blind gone all-in for 2200.