# How do you calculate side-pots when all-in on ante?

Tags: tournament, all-in

Could you please help me, i would like to know how to calculate main and side pots in tournament, when stacks of players less then ante + one/all of this players on sb/bb.

For example:

Blinds 250/500, ante 50,

stacks:

player1 30 - SB

player2 10 - BB

player3 5000

player4 2000

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See here: [How are side pots built?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/462/309) .

I don't think the rules about side pots will change if a player is so severely short stacked. In your particular case, I think it will be:

- **Main Pot**: 40 (10 from each player, since player 2 has the fewest chips)
- **Side Pot 1**: 60 (player 1 has 20 left, so players 3 and 4 also put 20 chips in. 3 x 20 = 60).
- **Side Pot 2**: 40 (players 3 and 4 pay the whole ante, since they can afford it. So 20 each (the rest of 30 is in the main pot and in the 1st side pot) = 2 x 20 = 40).

All this is preflop, before any action.

Comment: Wow, it's rare someone beats me to an answer while I'm typing it on poker.stackexchange.com :).  Weird timing!

Comment: @CoryKendall I was actually surprised the question remained unaswered for 6 hours...