# how does zynga poker works

Tags: texas-hold-em

I know some rules of normal Texas Hold'em (I am a beginner of poker), but what I don't understand is the rules of zynga poker on facebook. It's absolutely normal there, that people with worse combination beat people with better combination eg:

```
Nur won the pot ($2,884) with one pair of J's and K kicker. << worse cards but better win
Petr won the pot ($220) with two pairs J's and 2's with K kicker. << better cards but almost no win
```

also: how is it possible that multiple people win there each turn? Shouldn't only 1 person with best hand win?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That suggests to me that you didn't have enough money to win the whole pot so there was a sidepot.

You won the main pot with the best hand, but because the other player had more chips invested then you could afford. He won the remainder of the chips.

I would suggest you go and google side pots.

Or look at the following question on this site:

[How are side pots built?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/462/how-are-side-pots-built)