# I don't understand a hand

Tags: texas-hold-em

I've got A♠J♠

The other player has 6♥2♠

Board is: Q♣J♣8♣8⋄7♥

He wins 7k and I won 1k.

Why?

Comment: Is this a trick question? I dont even know where to begin. Stack sizes? Action on all relevant streets? Search for how to determine the winning hand on this site.

Comment: I'm a novice, I just thought my hand was a better winning hand. I'll take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Did you happen to be all-in for 500? As you can only win the amount of your stack from each opponent. So if the opponent went all-in for 7,500 and you call with only 500:

**If he wins the hand:** He will win 8k

**If you win the hand:** You will win 1k (2 x 500), he will take back the extra 7k

---

Check out this question for more information to help you understand:
[How is the pot split in this texas holdem hand?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/how-is-the-pot-split-in-this-texas-holdem-hand)