# Why did i win a portion of pot in this hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, hand, side-pots

I am the player with the hand Q♠T⋄. After the turn, I was thinking that anyone with a 4 would win the full pot. I am surprised that I won 286 of the pot. Can someone please explain how this works? I searched online, but couldn't find any explanation for this.

[image: Screenshot of the hand]

Comment: The 48 is all in. There must have been a side pot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are side pots built?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/462/how-are-side-pots-built)

Comment: The player with 4-8 won the pot, but he had only $1280, so he could only win $1280 from you and $1280 from each other player. Whatever remained in the pot after that goes the player with the next best hand who had money to cover the remaining bets, i.e., you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** A side pot is a pot when certain players have no participation due to lacking the required amount of chips. It is the way to accept bets when players have different chips amounts. This situation can only occur when involved active players are all-in or under special circumstances in the table rules or online poker services.

**Disclaimer**: *With such screenshot we are unable to see the whole hand history*. The only possibility for you to win a pot like that is that the pot you won is a *side pot*. A *side pot* is a pot in which a player who went all-in could not participate due to not having enough chips to call an all-in bet. Take this example:

- Player A bets 100 chips.
- Player B calls 100 chips.
- Player C wants to participate but can only call with their all-in, which is 70 chips only.

In this case, players A B C make a main pot from the lower amount of each bet: 70, 70, 70 (210 total pot). The remaining players make an additional pot for the remaining quantities: players A B make a *side pot* (a pot which is not the main, where every active player has equal participation) of 30 30 (60 total pot).

In the case player C wins, will only win 210 chips, and players A B will dispute their hands for the A B pot: who will win the remaining 60.

This case could also arise:

- Player A bets 100 chips.
- Player B calls all-in with 90 chips.
- Player C calls all-in with 60 chips.

Pots: A B C (60 60 60 = 180 chips), Sidepot A B (30 30 = 60 chips), Sidepot A (10 chips, returned immediately to A after the hand resolves).

Either case, you seem to be the player A (notice how C is all-in).