# How to divide an irregular split pot?

Tags: texas-hold-em

There's a 3 way all in pre-flop.
The stacks are 50,000, 25,000 and 10,000.
The big and small stacks both have AQ, middle stack has KK. Ace comes on the river (of course!) to knock out the middle stack.
How are the middle stack's chips divided?

Comment: Do you know [what a side-pot is and how it works](http://poker.stackexchange.com/a/469/4121)?

Comment: @Nij The wording isn't the best, but I imagine the question would better asked if there were, say, 10000 chips in a four way pot, one person folds, and it chops 3 ways, with all players having chips behind.

Comment: That would make it a completely different question, though. This is a three-way with two different all-ins and one covering; you describe just a regular chop.

Comment: Yeah it isn't a typical chop, 3 different sized stacks, 2 with the same hand.

Comment: In practice that is just two pots.  The last 25,000 from the big stack should just be immediately returned when betting closed for that round rather than pulling to the center as no other player was competing for that money.

Answer (score 1):

All three played compete for the first 10000 bet amounts. Two of them tie and split the pot, so each receives half of three times 10000, a win of 15000.

Only two players compete for the next 15000 bet amounts. One wins and takes all of it, so they receive two times 15000, a win of 30000.

Only one player competes for the next 25000 bet amounts. This is immediately awarded (in practise, returned to that player).

As a result, the AQ player who put in 10000 receives 15000. The AQ player who put in 50000 receives 70000. The KK player who put in 25000 receives 0.