# Complete all-in rules of fixed-limit hold-em

Tags: texas-hold-em

I have been having a hard time finding the full rules of fixed-limit poker pertaining to all-ins.

For example,

**Scenario #1:**

Fixed bet size of $20, capped at 4 bets.

Player 1 bets all-in for $5.

Player 2 raises all in to $10.

Player 3 has a full stack and wishes to raise. What size is the raise? $20? $30?

**Scenario #2:**

Fixed bet size of $20, capped at 4 bets.

Player 1 bets all-in for $5.

Player 2 raises all in to $10.

Player 3 re-raises all-in to $15.

Player 4 re-raises all-in to $20.

Is player 5 allowed to re-raise? Technically there has already been a bet and three raises, for a total of 4 bets so is the action capped?

I understand these scenarios are extremely rare but I have not been able to find the exact rules for these situations.

Also, I understand the rules may vary from card room to card room, but I'd assume they are uniform across online poker software.

Comment: related: https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/462/how-are-side-pots-built

Comment: Can you clarify whether this is pre or post-flop, the blind structure, and the positions of the players? That can affect the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As always, house rules vary. But generally speaking in fixed limit games, a player facing a less-than-limit bet cannot raise, but has the option to *complete* the partial bet to a full bet, which can then be raised by later players. So in your first scenario, player 3 could complete to $20, player 4 could raise to $40, etc., and the 3-raise cap would happen at $80.

That said, there are some rooms that use a "half bet" rule; that is, if the incomplete bet is half or more of the limit, then it is considered complete. In this case, player 3 would make it $30, and this would be considered the first raise, the next being $50, and the cap being $70 (assuming no other half-bets).

In scenario 2 under standard rules, player 4 has completed the first bet, and player 5 may raise to $40, and the cap is $80. Under half-bet rules, player 5 may raise to $30 (because player 2's $10 bet is the first complete bet), and the cap would be $70.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, player 2 is not raising, but rather calling, as the minimum bet is $20. So player 3 would have the option of raising to $40.

Example 2 is similar. None of the first 4 players are technically raising, so player 5 does have the option to raise to $40.