# How are pots built with folded players

Tags: texas-hold-em, side-pots

I am trying to implement how pots are built involving folded players. Any additional examples that demonstrate all the edge cases are appreciated.

For example:

```
A is all-in with 100
B is all-in with 75
C is all-in with 50
D is all-in with 25
E raises to 120
F calls 120
G folds with 80 wagered
H folds with 110 wagered
```

In the next round pots are built this way:

```
Side pot with 300 involving A B C D E F
Side pot with 175 involving A B C E F
Side pot with 150 involving A B E F
Side pot with 105 involving A E F
Running pot with 50 involving E F
```

A running pot is the current active pot that is being built.

Is this definition correct?

Comment: The first side pot should be 200, think its a typo. Rest of the pots check out, although i wouldn't really say its a definition, more of an example of split pots.

Comment: Ah the extra 100 was coming from previous running pot I forgot to mention.

Comment: Yeah, the max a player can win is their stack, so you can think of it as subtracting 25 from everyone, putting that into D's pot, then you do the same thing until you're done.

Comment: "Is this definition correct?" Yes, and search those tags and you will be able to find the answer you seek. Your question is confusing, your terminology is not very standard, all your asking about is side pots and that question is answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are side pots built?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/462/how-are-side-pots-built)

Comment: I took my example from that question, but it doesn't mention folded players, which my question specifically asks for.